# What does the 'Enterprise Ready' mean?

Tags: computer-science

What do you mean by saying that something is 'Enterprise Ready'?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Depends where it's coming from.  If its a vendor than it generally means "We haven't tested this in an environment anywhere near as large and complex as yours but we are crossing our fingers and hoping it will scale to your requirements".  If it comes from your own IT department it generally means "We've tested this as much as we can in a few of our qa environments and it didn't completely blow up.  We would like to test it in your production environment please"

Answer (score 7):

Enterprise Ready, in my interpretation which lies far from experienced with a project that claims it, is a marketing lingo for saying that software is robust enough to be deployed to a large environment: hundreds, thousands, or hundreds of thousands of users.  This also includes the ability to support a large user base so that the software is does not disrupt business [for long] in the event that something is not right.

Ultimately, I think it's a buzz word to provide entry into markets with large corporations and increase the cost associated with a product.

Answer (score 4):

Normally it means that it is expensive.

On a more serious note:

- Secure
- Scalable
- Stable
- easy to run in production

Comment: It should also mean full (and tested) support for disaster recovery.

Answer (score 1):

There is no "industry standard" definition for this phrase. For my money, it is a null-phrase used by marketers to impress the easily impressed.

Answer (score 1):

Typically it should mean the following:

- It's a client/server application (or something similar) that supports many users.
- The application can be administrated in a convenient way.
- Documented APIs allow integration with your other enterprise applications.
- The software maker or integrator provides the on-site support you need to achieve the above.

Answer (score 0):

Also often means that there is a support hotline to call when things break.  In hardware you often have enterprise and consumer class.
With the consumer you can buy it in the store and may not get a person or hotline to call.
With enterprise you normally have to buy though a partner and normally get a support contract with it.

So in the end it will be more expensive, but unless your a really large company like Google who can make your own OS and hardware, your better paying more and getting the enterprise class (normally enterprise grade will have an RMA option with SLA's)

Answer (score -1):

Apart from the ones mentioned above, Enterprise Ready also means

- It should have sufficient tooling to carry out development in a quick manner
- It should be easier to support, debug & maintain